# How to convert .PAT file to .PNG?

Tags: html, bash, graphics

I've got around 1000 different .pat files (pattern graphics). How can I mass convert them to PNG to be able to display them on a website? Best would be to use command-line tool like imagemagick.

Comment: ImageMagick doesn't support that file format: https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this would be with Reaconverter which costs money, and in your case would not be very efficient.